# phantomjs and basic HTTP auth

Tags: phantomjs

I make request to my router page (ASUS N10) and have some problems:

```
page.settings.userName='admin';
page.settings.password='admin';
page.customHeaders={'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('admin:admin')};
```

but in logs i see:

```
= onResourceReceived()
  id: 1, stage: "end", response: {"contentType":null,"headers":[],"id":1,"redirectURL":null,"stage":"end","status":401,"statusText":"Authorization Required","time":"2016-05-08T14:09:18.755Z","url":"http://192.168.0.1/"}
```

this is my problem:

```
  "statusText":"Authorization Required"
```

I tried it on another router from tp-link with basic auth and everything worked perfectly.

Need some help)

Comment: my login\pass is correct

Comment: take a screenshot, you'll probably see basic auth dialog

Comment: AdamSkywalker, page.render show black image) nothing to show

Comment: check if headers are present in request. you can use httpbin for example

Comment: `{
            "name": "Authorization",
            "value": "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
        }`
yes, headers are present in request